# Как установить PyInstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Пишу `pip install pyinstaller`
 Ответ:

```
RROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\nkikd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\nkikd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\nkikd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lzyxxjgx\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (14 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\nkikd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "c:\users\nkikd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "c:\users\nkikd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "c:\users\nkikd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 5, in <module>
      import locale
    File "c:\users\nkikd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "c:\users\nkikd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\re.py", line 143, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\nkikd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\nkikd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\nkikd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lzyxxjgx\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Что делать? как быть?

Comment: В рабочей директории есть файл `enum.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Будьте внимательны, когда устанавливаете пакеты с помощью pip. Регистр имеет значение. сверяйтесь с PyPI перед установкой. Правильная команда: `pip install PyInstaller`

Comment: Нет, та же ошибка :(

Comment: Какая версия Python? И был ли до этого установлен PyInstaller?

Comment: Установлен не был. 3.8

Comment: Скиньте вк, скайп, или телеграм, там продолжим общение, если вы не против

Comment: https://vk.com/nickguy257